# How to create a loop that adds a series of img elements to the div alternating between the two images?

Tags: jquery, html, image, loops

I have a page with two img elements, two drop-down selects to change the images that are displayed and a button. When the button is clicked I want to create a loop that will add a series of those images displayed to the div,alternating between two images

Comment: <sarcasm>Have you consulted the world wide web first before posting? There's a new start-up company called the Google that can actually search the interwebs for you and give you an answer to this...it isn't a very big or well known company but, give them a shot?</sarcasm>

Comment: Do you have some code youre working on you can put into a fiddle? Ill help you out

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like so using a Ternary Operator:

```
for(var count = 0; count < imgNumber; count++)
{
    imgID = count % 2 ? 2: 1;
    $("#id").append("<img src='image_'"+imgID+"");
}
```

Hope this helps.